# Instagram API endpoint

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I've tried many ways to use Instagram's API. Many repositories in GitHub have APIs using PHP, but all are obsolete.

https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/

I couldn't find endpoints or some way to working with Instagram's API using PHP since there were changes in April. Could someone help me?

I'd like to get some functions like follow and unfollow people.

I'm using Sandbox Mode and have already authorized some accounts for testing, but it always returns me this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [meta] => stdClass Object
        (
            [code] => 400
            [error_type] => APINotAllowedError
            [error_message] => This endpoint has been retired
        )

)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What endpoints have you tried? Which ones aren't working? Have you tried the endpoints linked in the documentation (example, here's the [endpoint for users](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/).

Comment: Hi @aynber, yes, I have tried all endpoints linked in the documentation. These only bring me information and photos. I would like to follow and unfollow people using PHP.

Comment: Looks like it's been disabled. Read the note at the top of https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Answer (score 2):

Instagram no longer allows you to use API to follow or unfollow people. Look through [Instagram API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api) to see what is and isn't possible

Comment: Thanks a lot Guys :)